# AWS boto error message ImportError: cannot import name key

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto

```
>>> import boto
>>> c = boto.connect_s3()
>>> b=c.get_bucket('beaubeaubeau')
>>> from boto.s3.key import key
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name key
```

I am new to boto
Any idea why I am getting this error?

Answer (score 2):

I think you want:

```
from boto.s3.key import Key
```

`boto.s3.key` is a Python module and `Key` is a class contained in that module.